# Forward HTTPS Proxy Apache not working and no logs

Tags: apache, ssl, https, tls1.2, mod-proxy

I'm a newbie to Apache and have configured apache Forward HTTP proxy already and working fine. I have enabled SSL web server with a signed certificate and web link is reaching in https port https://:3299

I have enabled required modules ,

> mod_proxy_http.so
>   mod_proxy_http2.so
>   mod_proxy.so
>   mod_proxy_connect.so

```
SSLEngine On
'SSLProxyEngine On
AllowCONNECT 3299 
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On                    
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off'
```

But still the forward proxy is not working through HTTPS port 3299 and I'm getting the "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

There are no logs reported. ANy idea what I'm missing

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix issue by following steps

1. Add the ProxyRequests On and AllowCONNECT directives in httpd.conf file
2. Add name (as same as CN name in certificate) in virtual host directive as below

   Virtualhost sitename(same as CN ) :3299

now able to use HTTPS forward proxy using Apache